# C# params with at least one value

Tags: c#, parameters

How can I have a parameter of `params` with at least one value?

```
public void Foo(params string[] s) { }

public void main()
{
    this.Foo(); // compile error
    this.Foo(new string[0]); // compile error
    this.Foo({ }); // compile error
    this.Foo("foo"); // no error
    this.Foo("foo1", "foo2"); // no error
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just do:

```
public void Foo(string first, params string[] s) { }
```

Comment: I also thought about that workaround, and I think it is not that clean. Because the `first` string will not be part of the iteration in `string[]` _(if ever)_ which might not work for some cases. Is there no other way?

Comment: But what you're saying is that you're *always* going to have one parameter to start with. This solution reflects that as cleanly as possible.

Comment: @JohnIsaiahCarmona Then just concatenate them together: `new[] { first }.Concat(s)`. Now you can normally `foreach` over the result.

Comment: I want to add another option as of C#7 is to use `IEnumerable<string> strings() { yield return first; foreach(var str in s) { yield return str; } };`.  Use that as a local function and then you're solid.

Comment: @Licht What is so special 'C#7'ish about your solution?

Comment: @VarvaraKalinina What's special about it?  Absolutely nothing.  What's C#7 about it?  Local functions.  (See: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/ )

Comment: @Licht, Ok, I see now :)

Answer (score 7):

You cannot specify such conditions for `params` at compile-time.

However, you can check this at run-time and throw an exception if your specified conditions are not met.

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to require at least one param at compile time, but it's really hacky.

```
  public class RequireAtLeastOneParam {
    public string Foo(params string[] args) 
      => string.Join(' ', args);

    /// <summary>The purpose of this overload is to require at least one argument
    /// on any call to Foo. Because this overload exists, call with no arguments won't compile.</summary>
    public string Foo(params char[] args)
      => Foo(args.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());

    public void WontCompile() {
      string foo = Foo(); // compilation fails because this is ambiguous between the two overloads.
    }
  }
```

Comment: Very interesting solution

Comment: You can circumvent this by `string foo = Foo(new string[] {});` which is, probably, intentional in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the accepted answer:

```cs
public void Foo(string bar, params string[] bars)
{
    string[] strs = new string[] { bar }.Concat(bars).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I realized that it will not cater the case with no arguments. However, in-case if there are other arguments, this is approach is good.

**Original:**
Another way is to add an overload. In this way you don't have to do concat or any other logic.

```
public void Foo(int param1, string bar) {
    Foo(param1, new string[] { bar }); // calling method with params
}

public void Foo(int param1, params string bars[]) {
    // TODO: implement
}
```