# C# params with a required minimum of one value

Tags: c#, parameters

Is there a more elegant way of ensuring a constructor is always called with at least one value than what I've got here? I have done it this way as I want a compiler error if no values are provided.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly List<string> _things = new List<string>();
    public string[] Things { get { return _things.ToArray(); } }

    public MyClass(string thing, params string[] things)
    {
        _things.Add(thing);
        _things.AddRange(things);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on the comments, I have changed the code to this ...

```
public class Hypermedia : Attribute
{
    private readonly Rel[] _relations;
    public IEnumerable<Rel> Relations { get { return _relations; } }

    public Hypermedia(Rel relation, params Rel[] relations)
    {
        var list = new List<Rel> {relation};
        list.AddRange(relations);
        _relations = list.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Apologies for editing the code before in an attempt to hide what I was trying to do. It's easier to just paste straight from my code editor!

Comment: The only other _tiny_ bit to do as an implementation detail is to instantiate the `_things List<string>` in the constructor to the total length to avoid possible resizing: `_things = new List<string>(things.Length + 1);` But that's just a minor optimization (likely no difference). As for signature changes, I don't think so. (but note that this signature makes it painful if generating the array at run-time and wanting to pass that in and not using the `params` at compile-time; you'd have to separate out the first array element and build a whole second array for the rest of the parameters)

Comment: The caller could still pass `null` as `thing`

Comment: @Tim - I don't if I just have the params, I am adding the "thing" parameter in order to force a compiler error when no parameters are supplied.

Comment: @Nicholas - good point. My actual code is an Enum, but the point still stands

Comment: If you are looking for another addition, use a method to return the array rather than a property, as a developer can do a loop using `x.Things.Count`, which call `.ToArray()` on every iteration. Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229054(v=vs.100).aspx - "Do use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations." under the bullet point "The operation returns an array."

Comment: @Dominic - good point, i'll change my implementation to populate an array in the constructor rather than a List<>

Comment: @AntonyScott Be careful returning the same array every time. If you return the actual object reference, the calling code can modify its contents; I suspect this may not be desired. `x.Things[0] = "Hello World!";` Instead you may consider returning some non-alterable enumerable for the `.Things` property, and storing `Count` as a `readonly` constant pre-calculated in the constructor.

Comment: @Tim - I wanted this to give a compile error - "new MyClass();"

Comment: @Chris - excellent point. I've amended my code to return IEnumerable<>

Comment: @AntonyScott Unfortunately, this isn't much better. The calling code can _cast_ it back to the array and alter values. Perhaps consider using `foreach` and `yield return` the values (or returning an iterator)

Comment: @Chris how? I don't have any way to change the array other than the constructor. Besides, I'm not going to spend any more time making this code resistant to attacks, as it's internal code anyway. I just wanted to make it obvious what the intent is. And I think I've done that now. thanks for your comments though :)

Comment: @AntonyScott For sure, I totally get avoiding over-engineering code, especially when it's for internal use. A really quick way is to have `foreach(var thing in Things) yield return thing;` for the property body. And you're right; probably overkill for your usage in this sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# params with at least one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10445743/c-sharp-params-with-at-least-one-value)

Answer (score 15):

What about [Code Contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

```
public MyClass(params string[] things)
{
    Contract.Requires(things != null && things.Any());
    _things.AddRange(things);
}
```

> Code contracts include classes for marking your code, a **static analyzer for compile-time analysis**, and a runtime analyzer.

At least you'll get the warning from static analyzer. And you can turn off runtime analysis in Release mode to avoid performance hit.

Comment: useful to know, but not quite what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late answer, but it's possible to pass the the array as a constructor parameter and list additional value(s) inside `{}`

```
public class Hypermedia : Attribute
{
    public IEnumerable<Rel> Relations { get; }

    public Hypermedia(Rel relation, params Rel[] relations)
    {
        Relations = new List<Rel> (relations) {relation};
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe you are looking for the RequiredAttribute (available since .NET 3.5)

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx for more information.

Comment: Isn't that for form/input/database validation?